# How to remove sleep screen from Galaxy family?

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I have a Note2 and there is this annoying screen that turns my screen on just to show some purple bubbles, the clock and number of calls and messages. After a feel seconds it turns off again.

I understand that it consumes certain battery but I don't use it. I searched everywhere but couldn't find any tip on how to remove it.

Anyone could help me? 
Thanks

Comment: When does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is Samsung's "Quick Glance" feature, which triggers when a hand is waved over your sleeping phone.

You can turn it off in Settings -> My Device -> Motions and Gestures -> Air Gesture -> Quick Glance.

Comment: @EASI does it look like this: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-B6vPfDdVU50/UKCTteFoU6I/AAAAAAAAH4I/00BDJ2gmgZQ/s1600/SAM_0836.JPG  That **is** quick glance, but it may be a glitch. It is still possible the desk clock, or a similar looking day dream is being engaged.